# ITEAD PN532 NFC Module with Raspberry PI

Tags: gpio

I'm working on a University project involving Raspberry Pi and NFC.
I'm looking for an inexpensive NFC reader, and I found this: http://blog.iteadstudio.com/to-drive-itead-pn532-nfc-module-with-raspberry-pi/

Has anyone had any experience with it?
Or maybe you could suggest some other NFC reader?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some experience with NFC reader (access machine), i use this :

- ebay product :

http://www.ebay.com/itm/PN532-NFC-RFID-Reader-Writer-Module-kits-ISO14443-Mifare-1k-4k-For-Arduino-PIC-/190823271810?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2c6df40d82

it's for arduino, but with this web site :

http://hubcitylabs.org/nfc-on-raspberrypi-with-pn532-py532lib-and-i2c/

work on raspberry with the i2c bus (i use the UART for other device...).

i use this library :

https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/

because there is a dedicated forum with a very good support ...

good luck for your project :)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer, Gilles! I am surely going to benefit from that :)

Answer (score 1):

Buy NFC module arduino here: http://www.elecfreaks.com/store/nfcrfid-breakout-module-p-519.html

The NFC/RFID breakout base on PN532, which is the most popular NFC chip, and is what is embedded in pretty much every phone or device that does NFC. It can pretty much do it all, such as read and write to tags and cards, communicate with phones (say for payment processing), and 'act' like a NFC tag. If you want to do any sort of embedded NFC work, this is the chip you'll want to use!